# galaxy note 1 - snote - how to select and drag something i've drawn?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note, s-note

I'm using the galaxy note 1 running android 4.0.  I have S Note opened.  I drew a picture of a cat at the top left corner of canvas.  Now I want to drag my cat to the bottom right corner of the canvas.  How do I perform this select and drag?  I don't see any select tool.  Is it even possible?